# Add orderby to query

Tags: php, wordpress

Short question.
How to add order by date to this query?

```
<?php
           if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
           endwhile;

           if($post->post_parent)
           $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&depth=1&echo=0");
           if ($children) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the pages by using "sort_column" parameter, The parameter has different values. It accepts following values.

'post_author', 'post_date', 'post_title', 'post_name', 'post_modified', 'post_modified_gmt', 'menu_order', 'post_parent', 'ID', 'rand', or 'comment_count'.

```
wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&depth=1&echo=0&sort_column=post_date");
```